# How to add elements one by one and update in browser using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So as shown below , I have a function that is executed on a button click , and it adds 30 div elements to the document with some attributes.

```
var bar_counter = 0;
bar_lengths = new Array();
function createBar(btnObj)
{
    while(bar_lengths.length < 30){
        var size =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 1) ) + 1;
        
        if(size>50)
        {
            alert("Please enter a value between 1 and 50 only!");
        }
        else{
            if(bar_lengths.indexOf(size) === -1){
                bar = document.createElement("div");
                bar_counter = parseInt(bar_counter) + parseInt(1);
                bar.setAttribute("class","bars");
                bar.setAttribute("name","bar"+bar_counter);
                bar.setAttribute("id",size);
                bar.style.height=10*size+"px";
                var color1 = '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6);
                var color2 = '#'+(0x1000000+(Math.random())*0xffffff).toString(16).substr(1,6);
                
                bar.style.backgroundImage="linear-gradient(359deg,"+color1+","+color2+")";
                bar.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend","<font color='red' style='vertical-align: text-bottom; background-color:white'>"+size+"</font>");
                bar.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend","<font color='red' style='vertical-align: text-bottom; background-color:white'> </font>");
                var place_to_insert = document.getElementById("placeBars");
                place_to_insert.appendChild(bar);
                bar_lengths.push(size);
            }
        }
    }
    btnObj.disabled=true;
    temp="";
    for(var i= 0; i < bar_lengths.length; i++) {
        temp = temp+bar_lengths[i]+" , ";
    }
    document.getElementById("YourArray").innerHTML = temp;
}
```

It is working perfectly , but on button click , the browser window is instantly populated with 30 div elements.
What i want to do is add a delay to this loop to show them getting added one by one in the window. How can i do it? I tried using setTimeout() and setInterval() functions , but it didn't work. TIA.

~regards

Comment: with some time delay this will become an asynchronous process, and the consequences will have to be managed

Comment: Any hints on how to add that delay in this loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this helper function to "pause" the execution of your code with the duration you want:

```
function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

and then `await timeout(3000)`.

Note that the outer function needs to be `async` in order to use `await` inside it

Comment: Bravo! This works like a charm! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Loop with delay simple method...

```js
const loopCountMax = 30
  ;
let loopCount   = 1  
  , refInterval = setInterval(() =>
      {
        // code of your stuff
        // ...

      if (++loopCount > loopCountMax  ) clearInterval(refInterval)
      }
      , 1000); // delay value
```